# Refreshing JWT and securing sessions on client side app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, jwt

I have a react app with a node/express back end.  I am currently using JWT to make calls to protected routes on the back end.  This all works fine.  But I want to keep the user logged in for more than just 30 min or so.

What is the best way to handle securing sessions or refreshing an access token when it expires on a client side application?

My Solutions:

**-One:**

Create a refresh and an access token.  Have the access token be short lived.  And sign the refresh token with a unique id given to the user in the database.  Then check verify the token with this id.  Then when the access token expires send a 401 back and then get the refresh token from local storage to create new tokens and then try the call again.

*Problem with this:* there is a lot of back and forth going on and it seems slow.

**-Two**

Send both the refresh token and the access token on each call and if the access token is expired use the refresh token to create new tokens then proceed.

*Problem with this:* I don't see why I would then need to send 2 tokens I could just send one and get the job done with that.  But then if one or both tokens become compromised they could regenerate forever.

**-Three**

Send the access token expiration to the front end and if the token is expired send the refresh token and verify it with the unique identifier in the database.  Then generate new tokens and continue.

*Problem with this:* Not sure how secure this would be.  But for now this seems like the best solution.

So I am wondering what is the best way to handle refreshing an access token when it expires so the user can keep using the platform?

Answer (score 0):

I'm saying this from experience not a source but the whole idea of JWT s that it's sessionless. there's another solution for handling sessions.
With jwt, you don't need to save it in your database as you sign that JWT with a secret key and you can just verify that JWT has been issued using your secret key. and you can issue that JWT to be valid for more than 30 minutes. It's totally fine. I myself have set it to 180 days. and because it's so long, a user will log in again in this time so you don't have to worry about expiration. but if you want to handle that too, you can parse it in your front end and check it's expiration timestamp and get another JWT before it expires.

Comment: So how do you handle things like user privileges like telling whether a user in an admin or not?  Do you just add that to the token? Do you think I should just issue one token and do something like reissue one every time a user first enters the site or just not worry about it.  If your tokens are so long lived how do you protect against the unlikely event of someone gaining access to the token.